# Is Dictionary good fo storing multiple values from database?

Tags: c#

I have query like these.

```
SELECT ID,Name,Colour,Price,Tax FROM SomeTable
```

That should retrieve around 300 unique rows.

Then I would periodically access those retrieved rows and use part of retrieved data in my application.

The data will be used quite often, but ever only around 30 rows at the time. I never know which 30 rows will be displayed so I want to have all 300.

I can do this with sql query to load those 30 rows that I need each time I need them, but I would like to pull all of the rows and fill some List, Array, Dictionary and then use those. Goal is to avoid constant calls to the database.

---

What would be the most efficient way to achieve these?

Can Dictionary have something like `Dictionary<ID(Key),ValueName,ValueColour,ValuePrice,ValueTax>`?

Or is Dictionary wrong choice for something like these?

---

P.S. Probably there is better way to do this with the use of Entity framework or something else, but I am doing this for practice. Started learning C# 15 days ago, and eventualy I will get to more advanced stuff.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the Dictionary is perfectly fine.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Are you familiar with a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue1, TValue2...TValuen>`? because I'm not...

Comment: I'm worried about `Tax(bunch values)`. Does this column holds delimited values? If so, you should read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: That is one of the reason I am asking, I saw Dictionary<Key,Value> but i can't find Dictionary<OneKey, value1. value2, valueN>

Comment: No there is one ID, and there are multiple columns. Like Dictionary<Key,Value1,Value2,Value3>. Is that viable?

Comment: Why do you want a `Dictionary<Key,Value1,Value2,Value3>` instead of a `Dictionary<Key,TypeContainingPropertiesValue1andValue2andValue3>`?

Comment: I didn't look at Dictionary in that way. Some of these answers explained a lot more then some tutorials. Thank you.

Comment: I assume you know that the rows wont change in the database while you have them in memory? How do you determined which 30 rows to show? What is the search criteria?

Comment: There are two search criteria, first is by Name, and then by colour. Yes i know that rows wont change. Acctually I just finished implementing and it works like a charm. What i missed from the begining is Dictionary<key, value> and value can be object. I really don't know why I tought that value has to be value(int, string...something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class to hold each row:

```
class MyObject
{
     int ID {get;set;}
     string Name {get;set;}
     string Colour {get;set;}
     decimal Price {get;set;}
     List<decimal> Tax {get;set;}

     // Constructor
     public MyObject(DataRow row)
     {
          this.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"].ToString()); 
          this.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
          // etc....
     }
}
```

Then store these in a dictionary

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();
foreach(var row in DataTable.Rows)
{
     var newObject = new MyObject(row); // Calls the constructor to load from the row
     myDictionary.Add(newObject.ID, newObject);
}
```

I've taken the easy option of making Color a string - but there are several objects tht you could use to hold color information, depending how it will be used.
Splitting the Tax field into a list is a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is <TKey, TValue>. So You cannot have multiple stuff like the way you said:

> Dictionary<ID(Key),Name,Colour,Price,Tax(bunch values)>

But nothing stops you from making a class/entity for all those properties and saving to Dictionary against the primary key column value.

Comment: Is there something else where I can have multiple stuff that would be aplicable in this situation?

Comment: Depends on what your scenario is. Dictionary is useful because its is quicker to search based on the key. You can use a simple List<TObjects> - but Search time is O(N).

Answer (score 0):

If your design goal is to supply data from in-memory data structure store then why not use Redis. Here is the link:
https://redis.io/

If you would like dictionary then it is key,value pair so multiple values for a key is not supported however you could have something like:

`<Key, List<Value>>`

cheers